# High quality pdf to eps

Tags: pdf, eps

I have always used `pgfplot` of `latex` to produce figures(.pdf format). Now, the journal in which I want to publish wants my figures to be in eps format.

I tried converting pdf to eps using `pdftops -eps fig.pdf fig.eps`. But the resulting eps file is of poor quality.

Original figure (in .pdf format)
[image]

Converted figure (in .eps format)
[image]

What is the right procedure to create eps file that is the same quality as my input pdf file?

**EDIT**

As per PooyaRaki recommendations: 
Inkscape option output(.eps)
[image]

Ghostscript option(.eps format)
[image]

Acrobat reader option output (.ps format)
[image]

Acrobat reader seems to work the best among the three.

Comment: Actually, it looks like Ghostscript produced the best result as Acrobat reader changed the colors.

Comment: GSView also works by clicking "Convert" and then the options "ps2write" and "600" resolution. I am relieved, as I am submitting a manuscript to PRL that requires EPS figures, and wasn't sufficiently adept with TeXstudio to alter the resulting pdf to eps there (although I've read that is its default?!). Thomas

Comment: I got good results with ipe: http://ipe.otfried.org/

Comment: It's crazy to see that none of the recommended tools can convert the image without a problem. How can there still be someone requiring images in this format if there is no way to use it to produce images of acceptable quality?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I recommend the following tools:

- Inkscape (Vector graphic editor, free & multi-platform)

  Can be either used using the GUI (open PDF, save as EPS) or using the
  command line (tested under Linux only):

  ```
   inkscape input.pdf --export-filename=output.eps
  ```
- Acrobat Reader (Linux Version) + ps2eps (TeXLive)

  ```
   acroread -toPostScript input.pdf
   ps2eps input.ps
  ```
- Ghostscript (multi-platform) Note: -dNOCACHE is needed to prevent
  GhostScript from rastering the fonts.

  ```
   gs -q -dNOCACHE -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=output.eps input.pdf
  ```

There are also the following tools. I didn't tested all of them and some raster the fonts :-( !

- ImageMagick convert (which might use Ghostscript itself. Calling it
  manually if more flexible and might avoid issues. convert might
  actually raster the PDF!)

  ```
   convert input.pdf output.eps
  ```
- `pdf2ps` (uses Ghostscript) + `ps2eps` (comes with TeXLive)
- `pdftops` (part of poppler), use the `-eps` switch for EPS output.

Note that EPS format does not handle transparency !

Comment: `inkscape` option performs no better-texts are not rendered correctly and `Ghostcript` option throws me an error saying `Unknown device: epswrite`. However, `acrobat reader option works`. The downside is that it dims the color(.ps format).

Comment: @SaravanaKumar epswrite is deprecated is newer versions try with `eps2write`

Comment: pdf2ps should be used with options -eps -level3, then it produces much higher-quality eps file.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov I receive `Unknown switch -eps - ignoring` and `Unknown switch -level3 - ignoring` with pdf2ps from ghostscript 9.22. You meant pdftops, right? With this, the options work but the resulting image is nevertheless a low quality image.

Comment: @0range, yes, I meant `pdftops`, thanks for the correction. It is strange that you get a low-quality image as it works for me. Some readers don't use smoothing, probably, this is the reason.

Comment: From my experience inkscape (on linux) gives the best results here. Font rendering is not an issue if the corresponding font files are installed on your system.

Comment: However when using `pgfplot` the best solution might be this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8646/160403).

Comment: For me, `pdftops -eps -level3` is still leading to poor-quality (low-resolution rasterization of vector graphics)

Comment: inkscape is the best

Answer (score -3):

The last answer is good, but ImageMagick doesn't necessarily raster the PDF. 
You can use:
    `convert -density 600x600 inpute.pdf -quality 90 output.eps`

Comment: Imagemagick always rasterizes a vector input. You cannot convert vector to vector in Imagemagick, even with the command from `@WenZhou`