# Inkscape PDF to eps conversion with matplotlib generated font

Tags: matplotlib, pdf, inkscape, file-conversion, eps

I usually create figures using matplotlib. Here is a minimal working example:

```
def cm2inch(*tupl):
    inch = 2.54
    if isinstance(tupl[0], tuple):
        return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl[0])
    else:
        return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl)

# matplotlib settings
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Rectangle
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times New Roman']})
params = {'text.latex.preamble' : [r'\usepackage{amssymb}', r'\usepackage{amsmath}']}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

figW = 17.9219/2
figH = 3.5*2.0
fig = plt.figure(figsize=cm2inch((figW, figH)))

x = np.linspace(0.001, 15., 500)

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8],
                    xlabel=r"x-axis",ylabel=r"y-axis")
xr_ = 0.5
ax1.axvspan(5-xr_, 5+xr_, color='C1', alpha=0.2, linewidth=0)
ax1.plot(x, 0.05*(x-5)**2, 'C0', label='cool plot')
ax1.axvline(5, color='C3', dashes=[4,2], lw=1.0)

ax1.legend(fontsize=6, loc=1)
ax1.set_xlim([0, 14.5])
ax1.set_ylim([0,1.1])

ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
ax1.set_yticks([0, 1.0])
ax1.set_yticklabels([0, 1])
ax1.tick_params(axis="y",direction="in")
ax1.tick_params(axis="x",direction="in")

yshift_ = 0.1
yshift_2 = 0.3
ax1.text(2*5-2.5, 0.48+yshift_2, r"value", fontsize=8, color='C3', ha='center')

fig.savefig('input.pdf', dpi=1000)
plt.show()
```

Output (saved as png instead of pdf):

[image]

I then want to convert the generated pdf to eps (note that I do not want to create a eps directly, for workflow related reasons).

I have read the following post: [High quality pdf to eps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736917/high-quality-pdf-to-eps/44737018#44737018). Unfortunately, I cannot use the Ghostscript conversion option due to the transparency in the pdf (as pointed out by KenS in [Converting pdf to eps without rasterizing or changing fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72981242/converting-pdf-to-eps-without-rasterizing-or-changing-fonts)), since the image is then rasterized.

However, Inkscape seems to be able to deal with the transparency without rasterizing the image. The command

```
inkscape input.pdf --export-filename=output.eps
```

**almost** does the job. The problem is that Inkscape seems to be unable to recognize the matplotlib generated Times New Roman font. The output is instead:

[image]

**Is there any way to teach Inkscape to convert the Times New Roman font created by matplotlib correctly?**

Additional info: I am using Mac OS and I do have Times New Roman installed according to the Font Book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use poppler library to import the pdf by using the `--pdf-poppler` option. However, that will convert text to paths.

So you can try with the following command:

```
inkscape input.pdf --pdf-poppler  --export-filename=output.eps
```